# How to use Wix binaries on Build machine

Tags: msbuild, wix, automated-builds

I am setting up wix without installing on build machine by keeping Wix binaries in the source code directory itself. When i configure the wixproj file based on the steps mentioned in the wix website

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <WixToolPath>$(SourceCodeControlRoot)\wix\[[Version]]\</WixToolPath>
  <WixTargetsPath>$(WixToolPath)Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
  <WixTasksPath>$(WixToolPath)wixtasks.dll</WixTasksPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

, it is not locating the local binary files When i change the WixTarget paths to local directory because in Wix.tagets file has the follwing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
  <Project
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
     <!-- All common targets/items/properties -->
     <!-- Version specific targets/items/properties -->
    <PropertyGroup>
    <WixTargetsImported>true</WixTargetsImported>
    <!-- MSBuild 4.0 -->
    <!-- MSBuild does not do short circuit evaluation of the AND operator, so we cannot have
         something like '$(MSBuildToolsVersion)' != '' AND '$(MSBuildToolsVersion)' &gt;= '4.0'
         instead set as default and override -->
    <WixVersionTargetsPath>wix2010.targets</WixVersionTargetsPath>
    <!-- MSBuild 2.0 - 3.5 -->
    <WixVersionTargetsPath Condition=" '$(MSBuildToolsVersion)' == '' OR '$(MSBuildToolsVersion)' &lt; '4.0' ">wix200x.targets</WixVersionTargetsPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Import Project="$(WixVersionTargetsPath)" />
  </Project>
```

commands which invokes wix2010.targets. 
In wix2010.targets,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved. Licensed under the Microsoft Reciprocal License. See LICENSE.TXT file in the project root for full license information. -->


<Project
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
  DefaultTargets="Build"
  InitialTargets="_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform;
                  _CheckRequiredProperties">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WixInstallPath Condition=" '$(WixInstallPath)' == ''">$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Installer XML\3.11@InstallRoot)</WixInstallPath>
    <WixInstallPath Condition=" '$(WixInstallPath)' == ''">$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Installer XML\3.11@InstallRoot)</WixInstallPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!--
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  Extension Points
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  -->

  <!-- Allow a user-customized targets files to be used as part of the build. -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <UserTargetsPath>$(MSBuildProjectFullPath).user</UserTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(UserTargetsPath)" Condition="Exists('$(UserTargetsPath)')" />
  <Import Project="$(CustomBeforeWixTargets)" Condition=" '$(CustomBeforeWixTargets)' != '' and Exists('$(CustomBeforeWixTargets)')" />

  <!-- These properties can be overridden to support non-default installations. -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND '$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)' != '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <WixTasksPath Condition=" '$(WixTasksPath)' == '' ">$(WixInstallPath)\WixTasks.dll</WixTasksPath>
    <LuxTargetsPath Condition=" '$(LuxTargetsPath)' == '' AND '$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)' != '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Lux.targets</LuxTargetsPath>
    <LuxTargetsPath Condition=" '$(LuxTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Lux.targets</LuxTargetsPath>
    <LuxTasksPath Condition=" '$(LuxTasksPath)' == '' ">$(WixInstallPath)\LuxTasks.dll</LuxTasksPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- This makes the project files a dependency of all targets so that things rebuild if they change -->
  <PropertyGroup> 
    <MSBuildAllProjects Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)')">$(MSBuildAllProjects);$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)</MSBuildAllProjects>
    <MSBuildAllProjects Condition="Exists('$(WixTargetsPath)')">$(MSBuildAllProjects);$(WixTargetsPath)</MSBuildAllProjects>
    <MSBuildAllProjects Condition="Exists('$(LuxTargetsPath)')">$(MSBuildAllProjects);$(LuxTargetsPath)</MSBuildAllProjects>
    <MSBuildAllProjects Condition="Exists('$(UserTargetsPath)')">$(MSBuildAllProjects);$(UserTargetsPath)</MSBuildAllProjects>
    <MSBuildAllProjects Condition="Exists('$(CustomBeforeWixTargets)')">$(MSBuildAllProjects);$(CustomBeforeWixTargets)</MSBuildAllProjects>
    <MSBuildAllProjects Condition="Exists('$(CustomAfterWixTargets)')">$(MSBuildAllProjects);$(CustomAfterWixTargets)</MSBuildAllProjects>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!--
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  Property Declarations
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  -->

  <!-- These tasks can be used as general-purpose build tasks. -->
  <UsingTask TaskName="Candle" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="Insignia" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="Lit" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="Light" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="Torch" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)" />

  <!-- These tasks are extensions for harvesting WiX source code from other sources. -->
  <UsingTask TaskName="HeatFile" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="HeatDirectory" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="HeatProject" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)" />

  <!-- These tasks are specific to the build process defined in this file, and are not considered general-purpose build tasks. -->
  <UsingTask TaskName="AssignProjectConfiguration" AssemblyName="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="AssignTargetPath" AssemblyName="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="ResolveNonMSBuildProjectOutput" AssemblyName="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="ResolveVCProjectOutput" AssemblyName="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />

  <UsingTask TaskName="CreateItemAvoidingInference" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="CreateProjectReferenceDefineConstants" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="WixAssignCulture" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="ResolveWixReferences" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)"/>
  <UsingTask TaskName="ReplaceString" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)"/>
  <UsingTask TaskName="GetCabList" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="GetLooseFileList" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="RefreshGeneratedFile" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)"/>
  <UsingTask TaskName="RefreshBundleGeneratedFile" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)"/>
  <UsingTask TaskName="GenerateCompileWithObjectPath" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)"/>

  <!-- WiX tools are 32bit EXEs, so run them out-of-proc when MSBuild is not 32bit. -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RunWixToolsOutOfProc Condition=" '$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)'!='x86' ">true</RunWixToolsOutOfProc>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!--
  Several properties must be set in the main project file, before using this .targets file.
  However, if the properties are not set, we pick some defaults.

  OutDir:
  Indicates the final output location for the project or solution. When building a solution,
  OutDir can be used to gather multiple project outputs in one location. In addition,
  OutDir is included in AssemblySearchPaths used for resolving references.

  OutputPath:
  This property is usually specified in the project file and is used to initialize OutDir.
  OutDir and OutputPath are distinguished for legacy reasons, and OutDir should be used if at all possible.

  BaseIntermediateOutputPath:
  This is the top level folder where all configuration specific intermediate output folders will be created.
  Default value is obj\

  IntermediateOutputPath:
  This is the full intermediate Output Path, and is derived from BaseIntermediateOutputPath, if none specified
  (eg. obj\debug). If this property is overridden, then setting BaseIntermediateOutputPath has no effect.
  -->

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Ensure any OutputPath has a trailing slash, so it can be concatenated -->
    <OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(OutputPath)')">$(OutputPath)\</OutputPath>
    <AssemblyName Condition=" '$(AssemblyName)'=='' ">$(MSBuildProjectName)</AssemblyName>
    <!--
    Be careful not to give OutputPath a default value in the case of an invalid Configuration/Platform.
    We use OutputPath specifically to check for invalid configurations/platforms.
    -->
    <OutputPath Condition=" '$(Platform)'=='' and '$(Configuration)'=='' and '$(OutputPath)'=='' ">bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <_OriginalConfiguration>$(Configuration)</_OriginalConfiguration>
    <_OriginalPlatform>$(Platform)</_OriginalPlatform>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <ConfigurationName Condition=" '$(ConfigurationName)' == '' ">$(Configuration)</ConfigurationName>      <!-- Example, Debug -->
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)'=='' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <_OriginalOutputType>$(OutputType)</_OriginalOutputType>
    <OutputType Condition=" '$(OutputType)' == '' ">Package</OutputType>
    <BuildProjectReferences Condition="'$(BuildProjectReferences)' == ''">true</BuildProjectReferences>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(OutputPath)' == '' ">
      <!--
      A blank OutputPath at this point means that the user passed in an invalid Configuration/Platform
      combination.  Whether this is considered an error or a warning depends on the value of
      $(SkipInvalidConfigurations).
      -->
      <_InvalidConfigurationError Condition=" '$(SkipInvalidConfigurations)' != 'true' ">true</_InvalidConfigurationError>
      <_InvalidConfigurationWarning Condition=" '$(SkipInvalidConfigurations)' == 'true' ">true</_InvalidConfigurationWarning>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Properties for the intermediate object output -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath Condition="'$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)'=='' ">obj\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath Condition="!HasTrailingSlash('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)')">$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <IntermediateExt Condition=" '$(IntermediateExt)' == '' ">.wixobj</IntermediateExt>
    <CleanFile Condition=" '$(CleanFile)' == '' ">$(MSBuildProjectFile).FileList.txt</CleanFile>
    <BindContentsFilePrefix Condition=" '$(BindContentsFilePrefix)' == '' ">$(MSBuildProjectFile).BindContentsFileList</BindContentsFilePrefix>
    <BindContentsFileExtension Condition=" '$(BindContentsFileExtension)' == '' ">.txt</BindContentsFileExtension>
    <BindOutputsFilePrefix Condition=" '$(BindOutputsFilePrefix)' == '' ">$(MSBuildProjectFile).BindOutputsFileList</BindOutputsFilePrefix>
    <BindOutputsFileExtension Condition=" '$(BindOutputsFileExtension)' == '' ">.txt</BindOutputsFileExtension>
    <BindBuiltOutputsFilePrefix Condition=" '$(BindBuiltOutputsFilePrefix)' == '' ">$(MSBuildProjectFile).BindBuiltOutputsFileList</BindBuiltOutputsFilePrefix>
    <BindBuiltOutputsFileExtension Condition=" '$(BindBuiltOutputsFileExtension)' == '' ">.txt</BindBuiltOutputsFileExtension>
    <SignedFile Condition=" '$(SignedFile)' == '' ">$(MSBuildProjectFile).Signed.txt</SignedFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" $(IntermediateOutputPath) == '' ">
      <IntermediateOutputPath Condition=" '$(PlatformName)' == 'AnyCPU' ">$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
      <IntermediateOutputPath Condition=" '$(PlatformName)' != 'AnyCPU' ">$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)$(PlatformName)\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
      <IntermediateOutputPath Condition="!HasTrailingSlash('$(IntermediateOutputPath)')">$(IntermediateOutputPath)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
      <CabinetCachePath Condition=" '$(CabinetCachePath)'=='' and '$(ReuseCabinetCache)'=='true' ">$(IntermediateOutputPath)cabcache\</CabinetCachePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <IntermediateAssembly Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)"/>
      <FinalDocFile Include="@(DocFileItem->'$(OutDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <WixToolPath Condition=" '$(WixToolPath)' == ''">$(WixInstallPath)</WixToolPath>
    <WixExtDir Condition=" '$(WixExtDir)' == ''">$(WixToolPath)</WixExtDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

it is looking C:\programfiles directory to invoke light.exe, heat.exe and all

How do i point the local wix files dirctory in **wix2010.targets** to run wix projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously I had configured:

```
<WixTargetsPath>$(SourceCodeControlRoot)\wix\[[Version]]\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
<WixTasksPath>$(SourceCodeControlRoot)\wix\[[Version]]\wixtasks.dll</WixTasksPath>
```

Then I changed as per the document i.e I added:

```
<WixToolPath>$(SourceCodeControlRoot)\wix\[[Version]]\</WixToolPath>
```

into the property group.

Once added, everything works fine.